# What is mesh geometry?

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

What is mesh geometry in WPF?

```
<MeshGeometry3D Positions="0,0,0 10,0,0 10,10,0 0,10,0 0,0,10 10,0,10 10,10,10 0,10,10"
                TriangleIndices="0 1 3 1 2 3  0 4 3 4 7 3  4 6 7 4 5 6  0 4 1 1 4 5  1 2 6 6 5 1  2 3 7 7 6 2" />
```

This is the code I have, and what is the meaning of the numbers in `Positions` and `TriangleIndices`?

Answer (score 4):

> MeshGeometry3D allows the developer to
>   specify position, normal, and texture
>   coordinate information. The Positions
>   property is required.
>
> Normals are assumed to be associated
>   with the front faces of a mesh
>   primitive. The winding order (the
>   order in which the Positions that make
>   up each triangle of the mesh are
>   specified) determines whether a given
>   face is front-facing or back-facing.
>   Front-facing triangles are wound in
>   counter-clockwise order; back-facing
>   triangles are wound in clockwise
>   order.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.aspx)

[Positions:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.positions.aspx)

> The points specifed by this property
>   represent the vertices of the
>   triangles that make up a 3-D mesh.
>
> The winding order (the order in which
>   the Positions that make up each
>   triangle of the mesh are specified)
>   determines whether a given face is
>   front-facing or back-facing.
>   Front-facing triangles are wound in
>   counter-clockwise order; back-facing
>   triangles are wound in clockwise
>   order.

[TriangleIndices:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d.triangleindices.aspx)

> For a triangle in a given 3-D mesh,
>   the order in which the triangle's
>   vertex positions are specified
>   determines whether the triangle face
>   is a front or back face.
>
> The Windows Presentation Foundation
>   3-D implementation uses a
>   counter-clockwise winding order; that
>   is, the points that determine a
>   front-facing mesh triangle's positions
>   should be specified in
>   counterclockwise order, as viewed from
>   the front of the mesh.
>
> Setting the TriangleIndices property
>   is optional. If the indices are not
>   specified, triangles are drawn in a
>   non-indexed fashion. Every set of
>   three positions becomes a triangle.

Comment: This answer copies text from MSDN, but doesn't really answer the OP's question, which (I believe) is how the point position indexes in the TriangleIndices array correspond to the triangles in the model. I believe the answer is that each group of three consecutive numbers in the TriangleIndices array defines a triangle, but this is not clearly stated in the MSDN text.

Answer (score 3):

**Positions :**

Each three consecutive sets of numbers present in the value of "Positions" attribute declares a 3DPoint with a particular index, that is first three numbers in the positions (0,0,0) defines a 3DPoint with index 0, and the next set of three numbers (10,0,0) defines a 3DPoint with index 1.

**TriangleIndices :**

This attribute's value holds all the triangles that make up the mesh. Any 3D Model present as MeshGeometry3D is made up of triangles, which are made up of Positions.

A single point ( which here is Position) can be reference in multiple triangles which is why Positions are separately defined in tag Positions and Triangles contain the indices of the Positions.

Comment: I finally understood, thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge (and not copying and pasting unlike others)

Answer (score 0):

With positions define the location on axes and each of them labeled (like v0(vertex 0) , v1 , ...)
So we can indicate what Triangle be on face, back ,...
In following, represent the index of mesh, vertex and TriangleIndices of cube. 
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTdf9.jpg)

So TriangleIndices for cube like this(note every face of the cube is on a single line)
 `0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,   //front
 4,  5,  6,  4,  6,  7,   //right
 8,  9,  10, 8,  10, 11,  //back
 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,  //left
 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,  //upper
 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23}; //bottom`

for more information see this http://in2gpu.com/2015/07/09/drawing-cube-with-indices/